# Alternatives to a deep & narrow inheritance hierarchy?

Tags: java

(Novice Java developer here, any responses would be greatly appreciated.)

I have created an implementation of a game, and several different AI's that play it. Lets say they all use the same base algorithm, something like Monte-Carlo Tree Search (MCTS). All of the AI's share this common template, but they all have slight differences. Each AI must contain the previous AI's modifications as I must demonstrate my progress.

Currently, I have an interface which defines the required methods of MCTS and an abstract class which defines implementations of these methods to perform vanilla MCTS (Unoptimised). The first AI I created extends this abstract class to define a concrete version. Then the next AI extends the first and overrides certain methods to modify the algorithms behaviour in some way. This kind of process is repeated so each AI extends the previous one, gaining previous alterations and defining its own.

This creates a deep and narrow like inheritance hierarchy, which has a consequence of being hard to understand. Is there a better way to create these AI's and change the inheritance hierarchy?

Comment: The alternative to inheritance is composition most of the time, but you really need to post code samples for people to give proper help.

Comment: Inheritance is a relationship of _is a_:  Class B _is a_ Class A.  A much simpler approach is composition, which uses a relationship of _has a_.  Class B would have an instance of Class A in it privately, which it can call methods on.  This creates some complexities with dependencies, but completely removes inheritance issues.

Comment: To expand on @ZachChilders comment with an example,  a `Goblin` _is_ a `Monster`, so it inherits the properties of `Monster`, but a `Goblin` might _have_ a `Spell` which would use composition.

Comment: Related to the has a relationship, look at the strategy pattern and compose the AI of the different methods.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-inheritance-composition For more reading on what others have explained.

Comment: Instead of creating multiple subclasses, is it possible to simply have the parent as an attribute? Something like ```class AI { AI parent; /* other attributes and methods */ }``` The root node would have a null parent whereas child nodes can store a reference to their parents.

Comment: My implementation does use the Strategy design pattern, as well as the template design pattern. Composition is not possible as far as I'm aware as methods need to be overriden from the inherited class, new functionality is not added so to speak but existing functionality is adjusted. I will attempt to show an exacmple tomorrow.